# Ladder Logic for PLC Program

Tags: digital-logic, plc, ladder

Having trouble understanding this ladder logic program. I can solve more basic ladder logic programs but I do not know how to account for small voltage adjustments. Here is the problem:

You are designing a PLC program which controls a cooling van on a vehicle engine.  The engine must stay at 205 degrees F.  The PLC should have 2 outputs for fan control: an output which turns the fan on and off, and a second output which is a voltage value which corresponds to the speed of the fan.  The fan speed voltage should be between 0 and 5 volts, where 0 V indicates a slow fan for 1 degree above temperature (206 degrees) and 5 V indicates maximum fan speed for 10 degrees above temperature (215 degrees).  The input to the PLC is a thermopile which is 0 V at 150 degrees F, and increases by 25 mV for every degree F above that.  The system should also have a third output which is an overheat light which flashes if the engine temperature ever reaches 15 degrees above the temperature setpoint (220F).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE you may want to review the guidelines on asking questions and edit your question, because you have not actually asked a question, you have only stated a problem. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also state the PLC make and model (and provide a link) so that we know what features are available. Post all this information **in your original question** and not in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what PLC you are using, I'll give you an example with a CLICK PLC. The [CLICK PLC](http://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Programmable_Controllers/CLICK_Series_PLCs_(Stackable_Micro_Brick)) makes this trivial as it has built in I/O on the processor and I'm using model [C0-02DR-D](http://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Programmable_Controllers/CLICK_Series_PLCs_(Stackable_Micro_Brick)/PLC_Units/C0-02DR-D) **$139** which has

- (4) 24VDC inputs
- (4) Relay outputs
- (2) Analog inputs (configurable as 4-20mA or 0-5V)
- (2) Analog outputs (configurable as 4-20mA or 0-5V)

The first thing is to scale the input. Some PLCs such as Allen Bradley's have instructions for doing this, but the CLICK makes this easier using a graphical editor. Here it is;

[image: Click PLC analog input scaling]

The temp input signal is connected to input **AD1** (analog to digital). We select 0-5V option. For scaling we set `0V = 150deg F` and `5V = 350deg F` (since 25mV =  1 degree).

```
5V = 5000mV   
5000mV/25mV = 200
150 + 200 = 350
```

The scaled input is saved in memory register `DF1` which is a 32 bit floating value address.

Now we scale the output;

[image: Click PLC analog output scaling]

The output fan speed output is connected to output **DA1** (digital to analog). Again, we select 0-5V option. `206deg F = 0V` and `215deg F = 5V`. For this output, we assign memory register `DF3`, a 32 bit floating value address. Notice on both Input and Output scaling, we selected the option `Enable Range Limiter` which tells the CLICK to ignore values outside of the limits.

Here is the Ladder logic. I included comments for explanation

[image: Click PLC fan control]

As you can see, it took only 7 lines of PLC code. I do this for a living, so I find this trivial. Good luck!

**CORRECTION:** On comment of line 3 in the ladder, I meant to say copy value of DF1 into DF3 not DF2.